# Rails rubocop don't indent the block after multiple condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

The code looks like this:

```
db_table
  .where('some condition')
  .joins('another table')
  .find_each do |table_record|
  puts table_record.name
end
```

Is there a rubocop rule that allows you to add indent after `do`?

```
db_table
  .where('some condition')
  .joins('another table')
  .find_each do |table_record|
    puts table_record.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Rubocop docs
this seems to be the cop you are looking for:

[Layout/IndentationWidth](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_layout.html#layoutindentationwidth)

Answer (score 0):

This in rubocop.yml helps me

```
Layout/BlockAlignment:
  EnforcedStyleAlignWith: start_of_block
```

It forced me to move last `end`:

```
db_table
  .where('some condition')
  .joins('another table')
  .find_each do |table_record|
  puts table_record.name
  end
```

and then rubocop force to use indentation